# Not able to generate amazon "GET_VENDOR_NET_PURE_PRODUCT_MARGIN_REPORT" using API

Tags: python-3.x, aws-api-gateway

I'm  trying to generate GET_VENDOR_NET_PURE_PRODUCT_MARGIN_REPORT but shows following error:

> Report Failed !
> {'reportType': 'GET_VENDOR_NET_PURE_PRODUCT_MARGIN_REPORT', 'processingEndTime': '2023-10-09T12:33:14+00:00', 'processingStatu

Code block have current code

```
import csv
import json
import time
import gzip
import pandas as pd
import requests
import seaborn as sns
from sp_api.api import Reports, Sales,Orders,VendorDirectFulfillmentShipping,VendorOrders
from sp_api.base import SellingApiException, Marketplaces, SellingApiForbiddenException, Granularity
from sp_api.base import Marketplaces, ReportType, ProcessingStatus, Granularity
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
from pandas import json_normalize

# Credentials

CLIENT_CONFIG = {

  "lwa_app_id": 

  "lwa_client_secret": 
  "aws_access_key":

  "aws_secret_key": 

  "role_arn":
  "refresh_token": 

              }

# Sales report Creation
# Specifying the report Options

report_Options = {

                    "reportPeriod":"night",

                    "sellingProgram":"something",

                    "distributorView":"reporttype"

                }
# Create Report - This will get us the reportID

report_type = ReportType.GET_VENDOR_NET_PURE_PRODUCT_MARGIN_REPORT 

res = Reports(credentials=CLIENT_CONFIG, marketplace=Marketplaces.US)

data = res.create_report(reportType=report_type, reportOptions=report_Options,dataStartTime="2023-08-18T08:31:00.000Z",dataEndTime="2023-08-19T08:31:00.000Z")

report = data.payload

#print(report)
# Report_ID

report_id =report['reportId']

# Report Creation

res=Reports(credentials=CLIENT_CONFIG, marketplace=Marketplaces.US)

data = res.get_report(report_id)



report_data =''



while data.payload.get('processingStatus') not in [ProcessingStatus.DONE,ProcessingStatus.FATAL,ProcessingStatus.CANCELLED]:

    print(data.payload)

    print('Sleeping..')

    time.sleep(90)

    data = res.get_report(report_id)

    print(data)

if data.payload.get('processingStatus') in [ProcessingStatus.FATAL,ProcessingStatus.CANCELLED]:

    print("Report Failed !")

    report_data = data.payload

    print(report_data)

    

else:

    print("Success:")

    print(data.payload)

    report_data = res.get_report_document(data.payload['reportDocumentId'])

    print("Document:")

    print(report_data.payload)





#print('')



#URL of the report

report_url = report_data.payload.get('url')



#print(report_url)

#print('')



res=requests.get(report_url)

#print(res.content)

#print('')



# Decoding the report content

t=res.content

s = gzip.decompress(t)

print(s)

#type(s)
```

I'm expecting report in JSON format but not able to get.